# Not able to increase price according to quantity in Ionic Ecommerce App

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on the Ionic Ecommerce App and In that, I am showing product quantity in the products page. The Problem is that it is not updating the price according to the quantity and When I am increasing the quantity of one product, All products quantity are increasing.

This is my productdetails.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Products</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-row align-items-center justify-content-center class="mynewr11">
 <ion-col *ngFor="let product of this.pdeta" col-5 class="mynewcol22">
  <img class="myimg11" src="{{product.image}}" />
  <p>{{ product.product_name }}</p>
  <p><strong>Price:</strong> ₹{{ product.product_actual_price }}</p>
  <ion-col class="qty">
    <button (click)="decreaseProductCount()" clear ion-button small color="dark">
      -
    </button>
    <button ion-button small clear color="dark">
      {{productCount}}
    </button>
    <button (click)="incrementProductCount()" clear ion-button small color="dark">
      +
    </button>
</ion-col>
  <button class="mybtn11" (click)="addToCart(product)" ion-button icon-left small>
    <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    Add to Cart
  </button>
 </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

In this view, I am fetching all products.

This is my **productdetails.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartProvider } from '../../providers/cart/cart';
import { CartPage } from '../cart/cart';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-productdetails',
  templateUrl: 'productdetails.html',
})
export class ProductdetailsPage {
  detailsp: any = [];
  pdeta: any = [];
  items: Object[] = [];
  itemsInCart: Object[] = [];
  selectProduct: any;
  totalPrice: any;
  productCount: number = 1;
  cartItems: any[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private cartService: CartProvider, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
    this.detailsp = this.navParams.get('productdet');
    this.pdeta = this.detailsp.msg;
    console.log(this.detailsp);
    if (this.navParams.get("productdet")) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('ProductdetailsPage', JSON.stringify(this.navParams.get("productdet")));
    }

  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.getSingleProduct();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProductdetailsPage');
    this.selectProduct = this.navParams.get("productdet");
    this.cartService.getCartItems().then((val) => {
      this.cartItems = val;
    })
  }

  getSingleProduct() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('productdet') != 'undefined') {
      this.selectProduct = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('productdet'))
    }
  }

  addToCart(detailsp) {
    var productPrice = this.productCount * parseInt(detailsp.product_actual_price);
    let cartProduct = {
      product_id: detailsp.id,
      name: detailsp.product_name,
      image: detailsp.image,
      count: this.productCount,
      productPrice: this.productCount * parseInt(detailsp.product_actual_price),
      totalPrice: productPrice,
    };
    console.log(cartProduct);
    this.cartService.addToCart(cartProduct).then((val) => {
      this.presentToast(cartProduct.name);
    });
  }

  presentToast(name: any) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: `${name} has been added to cart`,
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: 'View Cart'
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      this.navCtrl.push(CartPage);
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  decreaseProductCount() {
    if (this.productCount > 1) {
      this.productCount--;
    }
  }

  incrementProductCount() {
    this.productCount++;
  }
}
```

[image]

When I am increasing the quantity of one product, it is increasing the quantity of all products and the price is also not updating. Also, I am not able to fetch the product details from the addToCart function. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing all products quantity in single property on component. Instead you need to keep quantity on individual product and pass it to increase and decrease methods:

Try with the following:

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Products</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-row align-items-center justify-content-center class="mynewr11">
 <ion-col *ngFor="let product of this.pdeta" col-5 class="mynewcol22">
  <img class="myimg11" src="{{product.image}}" />
  <p>{{ product.product_name }}</p>
  <p><strong>Price:</strong> ₹{{ product.product_actual_price }}</p>
  <ion-col class="qty">
    <button (click)="decreaseProductCount(product)" clear ion-button small color="dark">
      -
    </button>
    <button ion-button small clear color="dark">
      {{product.count}}
    </button>
    <button (click)="incrementProductCount(product)" clear ion-button small color="dark">
      +
    </button>
</ion-col>
  <button class="mybtn11" (click)="addToCart(product)" ion-button icon-left small>
    <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    Add to Cart
  </button>
 </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

and component change:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartProvider } from '../../providers/cart/cart';
import { CartPage } from '../cart/cart';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-productdetails',
  templateUrl: 'productdetails.html',
})
export class ProductdetailsPage {
  detailsp: any = [];
  pdeta: any = [];
  items: Object[] = [];
  itemsInCart: Object[] = [];
  selectProduct: any;
  totalPrice: any;
  productCount: number = 1;
  cartItems: any[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private cartService: CartProvider, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
    this.detailsp = this.navParams.get('productdet');
    this.pdeta = this.detailsp.msg;
    console.log(this.detailsp);
    if (this.navParams.get("productdet")) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('ProductdetailsPage', JSON.stringify(this.navParams.get("productdet")));
    }

  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.getSingleProduct();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProductdetailsPage');
    this.selectProduct = this.navParams.get("productdet");
    this.cartService.getCartItems().then((val) => {
      this.cartItems = val;
    })
  }

  getSingleProduct() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('productdet') != 'undefined') {
      this.selectProduct = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('productdet'))
    }
  }

  addToCart(detailsp) {
    var productPrice = detailsp.count * parseInt(detailsp.product_actual_price);
    let cartProduct = {
      product_id: detailsp.id,
      name: detailsp.product_name,
      image: detailsp.image,
      count: detailsp.count,
      productPrice: this.productCount * parseInt(detailsp.product_actual_price),
      totalPrice: productPrice,
    };
    console.log(cartProduct);
    this.cartService.addToCart(cartProduct).then((val) => {
      this.presentToast(cartProduct.name);
    });
  }

  presentToast(name: any) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: `${name} has been added to cart`,
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: 'View Cart'
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      this.navCtrl.push(CartPage);
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  decreaseProductCount(product) {
    if(typeof product.count === 'undefined') {
       product.count = 0;
    }
    if (product.count > 1) {
      product.count--;
    }
  }

  incrementProductCount(product) {
    if(typeof product.count === 'undefined') {
       product.count = 0;
    }
    product.count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not increasing or decreasing. Now, the plus buttons are not working.

Comment: Missed to update this line:        <button ion-button small clear color="dark">
          {{product.count}}
        </button>

Comment: Showing NAN when clicking on plus button.  count: detailsp.count, this should be  productCount or only count.

Comment: Your solution is correct but the *ngFor="let product of this.pdeta", this.pdeta doesn't contain count. We have to fetch it from addToCart(detailsp) function. Thats why it is creating problem.

Comment: Initially count should be set to '0' on the product. Updated the answer check once. You can also set to '0' where you are getting the products.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but initially can I set it to 1.

Comment: Because I want to show price according to the quantity.

Comment: add this in constructor: this.pdeta.forEach(product => product.count = 1);   after this.pdeta = this.detailsp.msg;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186346/discussion-between-raghav-and-rakesh-makluri).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your UI, you display `product.product_actual_price`. But I don't think that you are updating the product, which means that the new price will not be displayed.

Also, I assume that `product_actual_price` should always be the price for 1 piece and not the total price. So why don't you just update your UI to display `{{product.product_actual_price * productCount}}`

EDIT:

You only have a single variable `productCount` that stores the product count. You have to keep track of the product counts individually (per product). So you can either store it on the product object itself or create a map where you store the productCount per item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now my price is updating but I am mentioned one more problem that when I click on one product quantity, all products quantity are increasing or decreasing. Can you help with that please.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.